# scikit_learn-0.14.1 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt freezes on test

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I just installed scikit_learn on my MINT-15 linux following the instructions at http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/install.html

When I run the test: nosetests sklearn --exe  I get the follow output and my terminal freezes:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sklearn/pls.py:7: DeprecationWarning: This module has been moved to cross_decomposition and will be removed in 0.16
  "removed in 0.16", DeprecationWarning)
......./usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py:1610: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  s = np.sqrt(eigvals)

Appreciate your assistance.
...........................

Comment: You are using old documentation. The current one is at scikit-learn.org. Please open an issue with the ouput of nostests -sv sklearn --exe on github.

Comment: Fixed it! Used show()

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Used show() to "show the figure.